# Do the HashSet set operators work based on GetHashCode() or Equals()?

Tags: c#, hashset

The C# HashSet defines many set operators such as ExceptWith(...) that require comparing elements to another collection.  Do these methods work based on the HashCode of the objects they are comparing, or are they using Equals()?

Comment: Both! Objects are compared first by hashcode, and then via `Equals()` (if the hashcodes match.)

Comment: Only using `GetHashCode` would be obviously broken. `GetHashCode` has (practical) collisions. Relying on hash equality is fine if you use a large crypto hash (say SHA-256) but not with a low quality 32 bit hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Anything* to do with hash codes should use both `GetHashCode` and `Equals` (whether by calling them directly on the candidate values or via an `IEqualityComparer<T>`).

Hash codes are *not* guaranteed to be unique: they're just an initial filter, effectively. If two objects are equal then their hash codes *must* be the same... but just because the hash codes are the same doesn't mean that they're definitely equal.

The hash code is used to very quickly narrow down a large set of possible matches down to a very small set of candidates which have the same hash code. (The hash set remembers both the elements and their hash codes, so that the hash codes can be checked without recomputing them each time.) Then each candidate in turn has to be checked with `Equals` to determine if it really *is* a match.

The same logic is used in `HashTable` and `Dictionary`, although potentially with subtle differences in implementation. (The [Wikipedia article on hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) lists several variations.)